# Serilog fails to load Sink's dll not referenced in the project but available in the application's folder

Tags: c#, .net, serilog

I've encounter following problem:

I'm maintaining a solution which contains multiple projects being executables.
The solution is using centralized package management.
I'm publishing all of the projects into the same folder, to avoid duplication of all dlls involved. This worked great so far.

For now, all projects used the same sink, a file sink. Now one project is also using a console sink and that seems to be a problem.

If I start one of the projects only having a file sink, I will get following exception:

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Serilog.Sinks.Console, Version=5.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24c2f752a8e58a10'. The system can not find the specified file.
File name: 'Serilog.Sinks.Console, Version=5.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24c2f752a8e58a10'
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyName, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, AssemblyLoadContext assemblyLoadContext, RuntimeAssembly requestingAssembly, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
   at Serilog.Settings.Configuration.ConfigurationReader.LoadConfigurationAssemblies(IConfiguration section, AssemblyFinder assemblyFinder)
   at Serilog.Settings.Configuration.ConfigurationReader..ctor(IConfiguration configSection, AssemblyFinder assemblyFinder, ConfigurationReaderOptions readerOptions, IConfiguration configuration)
   at Serilog.ConfigurationLoggerConfigurationExtensions.GetConfigurationReader(IConfiguration configuration, ConfigurationReaderOptions readerOptions, DependencyContext dependencyContext)
   at Serilog.ConfigurationLoggerConfigurationExtensions.Configuration(LoggerSettingsConfiguration settingConfiguration, IConfiguration configuration, ConfigurationReaderOptions readerOptions)
```

The failing project has no reference to the console sink (and no such sink configured), but as everything is copied into the same directory, the Serilog.Sinks.Console.dll is available.
If I delete the Serilog.Sinks.Console.dll, or adding a reference to it for the related project, everything works. **So this only happens, if the project doesn't reference the sink in any way, but the dll is yet available in the application's folder.**

What could cause this?

It seems strange to me that Serilog tries to load assemblies not being required by the provided logger configuration?

My config section looks like this (json):

```
"Serilog": {
"Using": [
  "Serilog.Sinks.File"
],
"MinimumLevel": "Debug",
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "Args": {
      "path": "MyApp.log"
    }
  }
],
"Enrich": [
  "FromLogContext"
]
```

}

And I apply the loaded configuration like this:

```
public static ILoggerFactory ConfigureLogging(IConfigurationRoot configuration)
{
    // configure Serilog
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
        .Enrich.WithProperty("Application", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?.Name() ?? "MyApp")
        .CreateLogger();

    // register with Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
    var loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory();
    loggerFactory.AddProvider(new SerilogLoggerProvider());
//...
}
```

Comment: It might help people familiar with the config parsing if you include a snippet conveying your config layout...

Comment: Thanks, I've added a snippet of my configs json and how I create my LoggerConfiguration.

Comment: Just a thought, this could be the reason: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/62522

Comment: Yup, that's it. The ConfigurationReader uses the Assembly.Load function wich will work only for assemblies referenced by the project. If a file from disk should be loaded, the Method LoadFrom has to be used. So its a bug, that the DllScanningAssemblyFinder looks up the folder for assemblies, which are then loaded via Assembly.Load.